# CKEditor multiple editables with same selector?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, editor

I am trying to create a general widget (component) which maybe a one item component, a list component (like tabs) or anything else.
Exp:

```
<div class="widget-component">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="widget-component-title">Title 1</div>
        <div class="widget-component-description">Description 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="widget-component-title">Title 2</div>
        <div class="widget-component-description">Description 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Components are defined outside the widget script and they only need to respect the defined selectors (widget selector, editables selectors). 
On a list widget case a title or description editable occurs more than once.
I have been digging a lot for a solution this is what i came across.

- http://ckeditor.com/comment/135051#comment-135051
  this solution works but it breaks the generality principle and also i have to keep track of index classes on repeated items.
- I even tried to extend the "initEditable" function inside [widget/plugin.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/widget/plugin.js#L1206) but because i did not want to modify the file (preventing my self from future updates) and i could'nt extend it by external script ("initEditable" not accessable) i let it go.

The best suggested solution i came across is [this here](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12524#comment:3) but it does'nt seem to have been implemented yet.

Any bright idea is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Hard to add anything to your question because it contains the answer at the same time. This is not supported and if you want such behaviour, you need to workaround it pretty heavily unfortunately.

Comment: I see, in fact this feature is critic to us and we are trying to find a workaround to this.
I will share it if it is an elegant solution. Are you guys thinking of adding this feature in the near future? Thnx

Comment: There are no plans to work on that, and to be honest, a PR would need to be pretty complete (and backward compatible) to be accepted as this feature is complicated and may break a lot of things. But I'm sure that other developers will be interested in your workaround so it'd be great if you shared it with the community.

Comment: Currently trying to do something similar - did you end up with anything useful? If so, would you mind sharing?